# Does _.find return a reference to the object? How to properly set a property of the result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash, co

I use lodash `find` to query object from array, then I set the property of that object but when I print out the array after setting this property, it is unchanged.

I would be grateful for some comments from someone more experienced on handling objects with lodash in JavaScript. Feel also free to comment on the way I formulate the problem or to edit the content to make it more easily searchable for other people via search engines.

Isolated code:

```
console.log('socket.io', token);
console.log(realtime);
let session = yield _.find(realtime, function(data) {
    return data.token === token;
});
console.log('session object to be set');
console.log(session);
if (!session.socket) {
    console.log('setting session for '+session.token+' socket '+socket.id);
    session.socket = socket.id;
    console.log('local reference after set');
    console.log(session);
    console.log('realtime after set');
    console.log(realtime);
}
```

Result, this is the output from `console.log`:

```
socket.io 268fc477-d4ee-4ed4-88cd-648539397df2
[ { token: '268fc477-d4ee-4ed4-88cd-648539397df2' } ]
session object to be set
{ token: '268fc477-d4ee-4ed4-88cd-648539397df2' }
setting session for 268fc477-d4ee-4ed4-88cd-648539397df2 socket /#iEqqcIsBbATDs1a-AAAB
local reference after set
{ token: '268fc477-d4ee-4ed4-88cd-648539397df2',
socket: '/#iEqqcIsBbATDs1a-AAAB' }
realtime after set
[ { token: '268fc477-d4ee-4ed4-88cd-648539397df2' } ]
```

Expected result, look at the last print, I want this object to be modified in the data structure that object originated from:

```
socket.io 268fc477-d4ee-4ed4-88cd-648539397df2
[ { token: '268fc477-d4ee-4ed4-88cd-648539397df2' } ]
session object to be set
{ token: '268fc477-d4ee-4ed4-88cd-648539397df2' }
setting session for 268fc477-d4ee-4ed4-88cd-648539397df2 socket /#iEqqcIsBbATDs1a-AAAB
local reference after set
{ token: '268fc477-d4ee-4ed4-88cd-648539397df2',
socket: '/#iEqqcIsBbATDs1a-AAAB' }
realtime after set
[ {
token: '268fc477-d4ee-4ed4-88cd-648539397df2',
socket: '/#iEqqcIsBbATDs1a-AAAB'
} ]
```

Public [gist](https://gist.github.com/marekyggdrasil/bfe6e5720d333a980174), feel free to also comment here.
I hope this question will be also useful for others.

Edit
Lodash [reference](https://lodash.com/docs#find) says `Returns the matched element, else undefined.` I am not sure if that means that it returns cloned object or reference to queried object.

Comment: Do you need to call `.value()`?  A bunch of stuff is lazily evaluated and won't resolve until you do.

Comment: Please detail more, `.value()` on which object, use it for setting value to property?

Comment: I mean that to get the result I think you need to call `session.value()`.

Comment: You mean to handle (resolve) the `promise`? Result is resolved because of `yield` keyword, I `use strict` the environment and code is inside a promise.

Comment: Oh.  Well that's what I get for not reading closely.  Sorry, carry on.

Comment: My bad, I should have include the `co` that the code is nested in, just didn't wanted to make it too confusing, in the output we can see the value as resolved so I though it is better to skip that part.

Comment: Could you include the function the code is nested in?

Comment: The problem is not with `_.find` which will indeed return the found element. I suggest you try `let session = yield Promise.resolve(_.find(realtime, function(data) {
    return data.token === token;
}));`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening is that the value you are yielding is an object, which according to `co` documentation will treat each value in the object as a promise to be resolved, and will return a (new) object with the same keys and values being the values of the resolved promises.

In your case, since the values of the properties (such as `token`) are not promises, the values are passed through as is, so the object which is returned *looks* like the one you yielded, but actually it's a new object, *not* the one inside `realtime`. The code inside `co` which is creating this new object is [here](https://github.com/tj/co/blob/master/index.js#L122):

```
if (isObject(obj)) return objectToPromise.call(this, obj);
```

To prevent this from happening, you need to do

```
let session = yield Promise.resolve(_.find(realtime, data => data.token === token));
```

If you had yielded a single scalar value, `co` would have complained that this was not a yieldable. However, since you yielded an object value, `co` interpreted it as an object-type yieldable. Which raises the issue--why are you trying to yield a non-yieldable in the first place?

As a final note:

> Lodash reference says Returns the matched element, else undefined. I am not sure if that means that it returns cloned object or reference to queried object.

Of course, `_.find` returns the found element itself, not a clone of it.

Comment: Just tested, works like a charm. Thank you very much, not only for solution but also for clear explanation, cheers!